# How do I reduce this group generated by some generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra

While doing some practice on simplicial homology in Hatcher's book on Algebraic Topology, I'm faced with some problem of reducing this group generated by some elements.

$$\left<e_n-e_{n-1}+e,e_1-e_n+e ,...,e_{n-1}-e_{n-2}+e, m-e_{n-1}+e_n, m-e_n+e_1\ , ...,m-e_{n-2}+e_{n-1} \right>$$

Observation: If I add the first $n$ generators in this group, I get $n \cdot e$, and if I add the last $n$ generators I get $n \cdot m$.

I'm not even sure on how can I possibly change the generators, I've seen sums, however, can we do subtractions?

Please kindly advise! Thank you!